# Configure yaml for standard env

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-api, gcloud, production-environment

I have deleted `env:flex` from my `.yaml` file and deployed to app engine with some other changes in other files. So now I'm switched to STANDARD env with instance_class F1.

With this instance class I'm not even able to upload a picture/image to my app, in debugger it shows the following error:

> Exceeded soft memory limit of 128 MB with 129 MB after servicing 34
>   requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.

Please someone from Google or who knows how to configure .yaml file correctly advice me:

1. how do i change instance class?
2. do i need to specify any other parameters like:

   ```
   resources:   
   cpu: 2   
   memory_gb: 2.3   
   disk_size_gb: 10
   ```

What is the practice?

And one more thing: I don't think my app has suddenly become so popular. I'm unexpectedly receiving 3000 request per day. Is someone hitting my app every 30 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

The standard environment doesn't support as granular resource specification as the flexible environment, there is no `resources` config in its [app.yaml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref). It only supports selecting pre-defined instance classes. From the same doc:

> **instance_class**
>
> Optional. The [instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) for this service.
>
> The following values are available depending on your service's
>   [scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes):
>
> **Automatic scaling**
>
> **F1, F2, F4, F4_1G**
>
> *Default*: **F1** is assigned if you do not specify an instance class along with the [automatic_scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling) element.
>
> **Basic and manual scaling**
>
> **B1, B2, B4, B4_1G, B8**
>
> *Default*: **B2** is assigned if you do not specify an instance class along with the [basic_scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#basic_scaling) element or the [manual_scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#manual_scaling)
>   element.

For the traffic, it's really hard to say without seeing the request patterns, there can be many, many reasons.

Comment: thanks, so regarding instance  classes, please confirm if im correct, i should just add instance _classe: F2 (for example) to app.yaml file and deploy to app engine?

Comment: Yes. Start with F2 and see if that's enough for your app, if not go to the next one(s). The highest amount you can get might not be as high as with the flexible environment ones, though.